# What hierarchies exist in different branches of Philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, metaphilosophy

If you were to map out different branches of Philosophy in a hierarchical nature **on multiple levels** in order to compare them what would some look like or could you point me to a reference that sorts different branches of Philosophy based on a trait into a hierarchy? For example, a hierarchy of Philosophies based on geography might start at western and non-western Philosophies and then within western you have Ancient and Medieval and so on.

Everything I have found so far lists different Philosophies at one or two levels.

Comment: Pretty close to this question -- http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/131/what-are-the-most-important-branches-of-philosophy

Comment: Thank you for the link, I surprisingly didn't find it when searching for dupes. I would have thought that question would be tagged with metaphilosophy. I have edited the question to hopefully make it more useful and not overlap the other one.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I haven't seen any that covered the breadth of topics/branches which you are looking for but I always thought something like that would be useful. Sounds like a good project. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this using a GIS for "map of philosophy":
[image]

Comment: Seems to say: 'Centuries of philosophy- conclusions: Quine and Feminist Epistemologies' /LOL/

Comment: @Tom hahaha, that's hilarious, I just noticed that too. XD

Comment: It's quite good, all things considered.

Comment: Thank you for posting this and thanks to stoicfury for the link. This is the kind of answer I was interested in. I'm accepting this answer for now but if someone posts a more 'maps' or a more complete one which would include Eastern Philosophies I would accept that.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking you wanted a visual map for EVERYTHING, but if you only want a rough list then something like this should provide the basics:

http://www.philosophybasics.com/general_map.html

See the navigation at the top.

Answer (score 1):

- the table of contents of an introductory test on philosophy might give some hint, as well as following subject headings in an encyclopedia like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy) or the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/). There is no explicitly written up tree of relations, but one that could be easily constructed.
- "The Sociology of Philosophies: A Global Theory of Intellectual Change", by Randall Collins, gives diagram after diagram (and copious explanatory text) of the influences of philosophers and schools on each other. It covers the world (East, West and in between) and from way back when til now (or mid 20th c).

Comment: As the kids used to say, it will blow your mind. Sort of a history of philosophy _plus_ how it all interrelated. __in pictures_! But the font size is a bit small :)