# What is a simple book summarizing Cartesian philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, descartes

I know a bit of French, so I can read Descartes' work directly, but I would prefer to start with a simple book which summarizes descartes' philosophy.

Comment: In English : Tom Sorell, [Descartes: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=kCNz9Nbe2JQC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: See also [Descartes](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/) with [Bibliography](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/#Bib).

Comment: thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA i'm a big fan of you on math.se for your answers on logic, you really have great knowledge right

Comment: Good "intellectual" biographies : Desmond Clarke, [Descartes: A Biography](https://books.google.it/books?id=W3D9KGVyz6sC&printsec=frontcover) (2006), Stephen Gaukroger, [Descartes: An Intellectual Biography](https://books.google.it/books?id=QVwDs_Ikad0C&printsec=frontcover) (1995), Richard Watson, [Cogito, Ergo Sum: The Life of René Descartes](https://books.google.it/books?id=IRvIQkLFD60C&printsec=frontcover) (2007).

Comment: The reading order issue might be better a separate question

Comment: @JosephWeissman really?

Comment: Possibly! In general questions should be as specific as possible -- hence the "one question per question" rule of thumb. If the problem is meaningful on its own, why not ask it as a separate question? You're much more likely to get a great answer if your question is as narrow as you can make it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descartes is one of few European philosophers whom one can read without any introduction from the secondary literature. Hence I recommend to start studying Descartes by the primary sources. You get a fresh impression of his thinking and you can form your own opinion:

- Discours de La Méthode
- Meditationes de prima philosophia

At most, a short survey of his life would be helpful: When and where did he live? His education at La Flèche, his move from France to the Netherlands and finally to Stockholm.

Concerning the discussion of Descartes' thoughts: The full edition of the meditations contains six objections from his fellow philosophers together with Descartes' reply.

And to answer your original question, e.g., *Cottingham, John (Ed.): The Cambridge Companion to Descartes.* (1992)